# How to handle setTimeout in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, wait

My goal is to create a traffic light. I want to loop through the colors of the lights (red, orange, green, orange, then back to red again) with a 10 second wait after the red and green images are displayed, and a 2 second wait after the orange image is displayed. This needs to be looped with no user input.

To implement the wait, I tried to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), but my loop does not seem to run.

```js
var trafficLights = ["RedLight.jpg", "RedOrangelight.jpg",
      "GreenLight.jpg", "OrangeLight.jpg"],
    waitTime = ["10000", "2000", "10000", "2000"],
    count = 0,
    x = 1;
while (x=1) {
  setTimeout(waitTime[count]);
  document.getElementById("RedLight").src = trafficLights[count];
  count += 1;
  if (count = 3) {
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="RedLight" src="RedLight.jpg">
```

Comment: X==1 (comparison) and not x=1 (assignment) in your while definition

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596128/traffic-light-using-javascript#comment72324549_42596128

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traffic light using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596128/traffic-light-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`window.setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

You can have your setInterval occur every second, and keep track of a variable that you increment every second. If the value is 1, change the image to red. If it's 3 (two seconds later), change the image to red-orange, and so on. And of course, when the value is 8, reset it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get you on the right track, try changing the items in the `waitTime` array to integers. Then, in your if statement, use `===` to check for equality. `setTimeout` also takes in two arguments. An anonymous function, then then wait time. In general, I would avoid infinite loops. Can you make an exit condition for the `while` loop? Take a look at my code below:

```
<script>
var trafficLights = ["RedLight.jpg", "RedOrangelight.jpg", "GreenLight.jpg", "OrangeLight.jpg"];
var waitTime = [10000, 2000, 10000, 2000];
count = 0;
x=1;
while (x === 1) {
setTimeout(() => {}, waitTime[count]);
document.getElementById("RedLight").src= trafficLights[count];
count+=1;
if (count === 3){
    count = 0
    };
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Images </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

var elem = document.createElement('img');
document.body.appendChild(elem);
elem.style.cssText = 'width: 640px; height:360px;';

var trafficLights = ['RedLight.jpg', 'RedOrangelight.jpg', 'GreenLight.jpg', 'OrangeLight.jpg'],
    waitTime = ['10000', '2000', '10000', '2000'],
    i = 0;

(function fn()
{
    elem.src = trafficLights[i];
    setTimeout( function()
    {
        i = ( i + 1 ) % waitTime.length;
        fn()
    }, waitTime[ i ] )
}())



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function runLights(a, i = 0){
  console.log(a[i].color);
  setTimeout(runLights, a[i].dur, a, ++i%a.length);
}

var tl = [{color: "red", dur: 1000}, {color: "yellow", dur: 200}, {color: "green", dur: 1000}, {color: "yellow", dur: 200}];
runLights(tl);
```